# Padrão de projeto Proxy, por que usar?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Este exemplo de padrão proxy pode ser encontrado na Wikipedia.

referência: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

O que eu quero saber é o seguinte:

1. Por que devo usar este padrão? Quando devo utiliza-lo? Por que ele é bom?
2. Como seria uma maneira errada de fazer este padrão?
3. Existem falhas neste padrão?
4. Mais alguma coisa a ser acrescentada?

Exemplo:

```
import java.util.*;

interface Imagem {
    public void mostrarImagem();
}

// no Sistema A
class ImagemReal implements Imagem {
private String nomeDoArquivo;
    public ImagemReal(String nomeDoArquivo) {
    this.nomeDoArquivo = nomeDoArquivo;
    carregarImagemDoDisco();
}

private void carregarImagemDoDisco() {
    System.out.println("Carregando " + nomeDoArquivo);
}

public void mostrarImagem() {
        System.out.println("Mostrando " + nomeDoArquivo);
    }
}

// no Sistema B
class ImagemProxy implements Imagem {
    private String nomeDoArquivo;
    private Imagem imagem;

public ImagemProxy(String nomeDoArquivo) {
    this.nomeDoArquivo = nomeDoArquivo;
}
public void mostrarImagem() {
    if(imagem == null)
      imagem = new ImagemReal(nomeDoArquivo);
    imagem.mostrarImagem();
}
}

class ExemploProxy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Imagem imagem1 = new ImagemProxy("ResOi_10MB_Foto1");
        Imagem imagem2 = new ImagemProxy("ResOi_10MB_Foto2");

        imagem1.mostrarImagem(); // é necessário o carregamento
        imagem1.mostrarImagem(); // não é necessário o carregamento
        imagem2.mostrarImagem(); // é necessário o carregamento
        imagem2.mostrarImagem(); // não é necessário o carregamento
        imagem2.mostrarImagem(); // não é necessário o carregamento
        imagem1.mostrarImagem(); // não é necessário o carregamento
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Felipe Jorge,

Proxy, traduzido diretamente quer dizer procurador ou representante. O mais importante é entender o ***propósito*** de se criar um Proxy Objeto é criar um **representante** de outro Objeto.

> Por que devo usar este padrão? Quando devo utiliza-lo? Por que ele é
>   bom?

Você deve aplicar boas práticas de design por diversos motivos, não se deve utilizar Design Patterns em todos os lugares, só por que você acha legal, lembre-se do propósito de uma técnica de Design. No nosso caso, estamos falando do Proxy, um representante, então quando vc precisar usar um Representante de um Objeto ou da modelagem de um objeto, você cria um Proxy. Um exemplo? O primeiro que me vem a mente é o proxy criado para fazer a chamada local de um objeto remoto, em Java. Utilizando RMI, e aqui eu não explicarei o que se trata, mas é a implementação do Java para RPC. O Objeto remoto que está em uma máquina virtual diferente, em outro lugar na rede, pode executar lógica de negócios. E você pode fazer essa chamada localmente, da sua **Java Virtual Machine**, mas pra isso você precisa de um **Proxy** para aquele objeto remoto, assim, você faz a chamada no objeto local, e *por baixo dos panos* - se você me permite - quem executa o método de verdade é o Objeto Remoto, mas a chamada você faz no seu **Proxy**

Veja mais sobre RMI [aqui](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI)  e [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/)

> Como seria uma maneira errada de fazer este padrão?

Bom, ainda usando o exemplo acima, você não precisaria de Proxy para um Objeto Local, pelo menos não normalmente. Mas podem haver várias falhas ao implementar tal Pattern.

> Existem falhas neste padrão?

Talvez as maiores falhas sejam as de não saber quando implementar, ou deixar de usa-lo quando necessário. Um exemplo é que ele pode ser muito útil para serialização de um Objeto que você não queira serializar. Ai você cria um Proxy para seu objeto e serializa esse Proxy.  Assim, seu objeto não precisa implementar `Serializable`. O que quero dizer com isso é que não existem falhas, mas trocas - Trade offs - Estes trade offs acontecem, pois a medida que você opta por uma solução ao invés de outra, vc cria algum outro tipo de requisito. Se você não serializa sua classe, e usa um Proxy pra isso, você tem entender bem o que está fazendo e criar mais uma classe, e assim, mas manutenção, como eu disse, uma troca.

(Mais sobre serialization proxy pattern):

http://java.dzone.com/articles/serialization-proxy-pattern

> Mais alguma coisa a ser acrescentada?

Enfatizo que é importante saber qual é o propósito de se desenhar uma classe ou um sistema usando um padrão, ou uma técnica, por exemplo, você sabe o propósito do DAO, não quero aqui estimular este tópico - DAO - apenas mostrar como a maioria dos programadores segue uma rotina de copiar e colar sem entender quais são os objetivos.